# Flink route stream dynamically to different kafka topics

Tags: dynamic, apache-kafka, routes, apache-flink

Flink's solution to dynamically route Kafka topics was to implement KeyedSerializationSchema and override getTargetTopic, but KeyedSerializationSchema is deprecated and KafkaSerializationSchema is supposed to be used instead. This interface does not provide getTargetTopic or something similar.

So, in Flink, how should Kafka dynamic routing work as getTargetTopic does not exists anymore?

Answer (score 2):

`KafkaSerializationSchema. serialize` returns `ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]>`
This `ProducerRecord` holds a topic. 
You could use a constructor like https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/ProducerRecord.html#ProducerRecord-java.lang.String-K-V-
to inject the topic.

With that in mind you only have to create a method like

```
String dynamicTopic(T element, @Nullable Long timestamp)
```

and your `KafkaSerializationSchema` implementation just have to use it

```
ProducerRecord<byte[], byte[]> serialize(T element, @Nullable Long timestamp){
    ...
    return new ProducerRecord(dynamicTopic(element, timestamp), aKey, aValue);
}
```

Comment: Absolutely true 100% and very simple. I must have a shortcut yesterday, not remembering that to create a ProducerRecord, you anyway have to provide a topic!